# How to not be in "offline games" on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

few weeks ago Google Play add a Offline games category in their store. My game needs Internet to work, so I added a `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`. But I guess that this is not enough, because many players gave me 1 star just because they was in Offline games and my game was there...

I thought that when I change my permission to `<uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` will solve my problem. But when I wanted to upload apk, Google Developer Console said that there is 0 Android devices that my game can run on.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: what are the other permissions you request? it could be some other permission causing this issue.